# Python Machine Learning/Data Science Project Structure

Tags: python

I'm looking for information on how should a Python Machine Learning project be organized. For Python usual projects there is [Cookiecutter](http://cookiecutter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) and for R [ProjectTemplate](http://projecttemplate.net/getting_started.html).

This is my current folder structure, but I'm mixing Jupyter Notebooks with actual Python code and it does not seems very clear.

```
.
├── cache
├── data
├── my_module
├── logs
├── notebooks
├── scripts
├── snippets
└── tools
```

I work in the scripts folder and currently adding all the functions in files under my_module, but that leads to errors loading data(relative/absolute paths) and other problems.

I could not find proper *best practices* or good examples on this topic besides some kaggle competition solutions and some Notebooks that have all the functions condensed at the start of such Notebook.

Comment: See if [this](https://github.com/IDSIA/sacred) helps (no personal experience).

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there are best practices in this developing area yet but, in addition to cookiecutter, there were some interesting ideas shown in a [tutorial](http://isaacslavitt.com/2016/07/20/data-science-is-software-talk/) at the SciPy 2016 conference.

Personally, I try to minimize the number of sub-folders in a project unless I have a really good way to distinguish them and have good reason to keep them separate. Bad organization is nearly as bad as no organization. I think best practice might depend on use case -- not every project needs the same amount of boilerplate.

Answer (score 3):

The University of Washington has released a project template for small scientific python projects (including data science projects) called [`shablona`](https://github.com/uwescience/shablona). Is that more or less what you're looking for?